# Can the MINI Wemos D1 ESP32 handle 5v on its GPIO pins?

Tags: power, esp8266, z80

I need to connect multiple data and address pins of a Z80 processor, which runs like the rest of my circuit on 5V, to the gpio pins of a mini wemos D1 Esp32. But I am not sure if the wemos can handle 5V input. I have tried to search for an answer but most of the answers I find are oppositions from each other. Some say it is ok to put 5V on the GPIO pins some say it will kill the chip.

So do I need to regulate the voltage or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [ESP8266EX datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) (Table 5-1 on page 18) says that the maximum I/O input voltage is 3.6 V. Use logic level shifters.